# How to correctly destroy an LLVMModule and LLVMExecutionEngine?

Tags: c, llvm

I have a simple program using LLVM-C:

```
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <llvm-c/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm-c/Target.h>
#include <llvm-c/Analysis.h>
#include <llvm-c/BitWriter.h>
#include <llvm-c/Linker.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
    LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();
    LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();

    LLVMContextRef ctx = LLVMGetGlobalContext();
    LLVMModuleRef mod = LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext("mymodule", ctx);
    LLVMTypeRef functype = LLVMFunctionType(LLVMInt32Type(), NULL, 0, 0);
    LLVMValueRef func = LLVMAddFunction(mod, "constfunc", functype);

    LLVMBasicBlockRef entry = LLVMAppendBasicBlock(func, "entry");
    LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVMCreateBuilder();
    LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, entry);
    LLVMBuildRet(builder, LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type(), 2, 0));
    LLVMDisposeBuilder(builder);

    char* error = NULL;
    LLVMVerifyModule(mod, LLVMAbortProcessAction, &error);
    LLVMDisposeMessage(error);
    error = NULL;
    LLVMExecutionEngineRef engine;
    if (LLVMCreateMCJITCompilerForModule (&engine, mod, NULL, 0, &error) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create execution engine\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int (*func_p)(void) = (int(*)(void)) LLVMGetFunctionAddress(engine, "constfunc");
    printf("%d\n", func_p());

    LLVMDisposeExecutionEngine(engine);
    LLVMDisposeModule(mod);

    return 0;
}
```

As is, it segfaults inside of `LLVMDisposeModule`:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/col/llvmtest 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
2

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff668fbcc in llvm::SmallPtrSetImplBase::erase_imp(void const*) () from /usr/local/lib/libLLVM-3.7.1.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff668fbcc in llvm::SmallPtrSetImplBase::erase_imp(void const*) () from /usr/local/lib/libLLVM-3.7.1.so
#1  0x00007ffff5d60f00 in llvm::Module::~Module() () from /usr/local/lib/libLLVM-3.7.1.so
#2  0x00007ffff5c62b5e in LLVMDisposeModule () from /usr/local/lib/libLLVM-3.7.1.so
#3  0x00000000004010cd in main () at llvmtest.c:44
```

However, if I comment out either the call to `LLVMDisposeExecutionEngine` or `LLVMDisposeModule`, it no longer segfaults.

What is the correct way to destroy an LLVM module and execution engine using the C API?

Comment: According to what you see here: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-dev/2014-May/059352.html LLVMDisposeExecutionEngine also disposes the module, so only call one of them, preferably the engine if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing two problems with listed code,

first problem and your query is,
when you called LLVMCreateMCJITCompilerForModule it added supplied module to the execution engine's module list, below is the cut code for the same in ExecutionEngineBindings.cpp:196

```
std::string Error;
EngineBuilder builder(std::move(Mod));
builder.setEngineKind(EngineKind::JIT)
          .setErrorStr(&Error)
          .setOptLevel((CodeGenOpt::Level)options.OptLevel)
          .setCodeModel(unwrap(options.CodeModel))
          .setTargetOptions(targetOptions);
   if (options.MCJMM)
     builder.setMCJITMemoryManager(
       std::unique_ptr<RTDyldMemoryManager>(unwrap(options.MCJMM)));
   if (ExecutionEngine *JIT = builder.create()) {
     *OutJIT = wrap(JIT);
```

so when you called LLVMDisposeExecutionEngine it had deleted all modules, listed in engine's list, so the proper way is you need to remove your module/s from list before disposing execution engine. (code is in the same file ExecutionEngineBindings.cpp:258)

```
 LLVMRemoveModule(engine, mod, &mod, &error);
 LLVMDisposeExecutionEngine(engine);
```

and second is JIT has not been linked in, there is no call to LLVMLinkInMCJIT() which should be before LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();

```
 LLVMLinkInMCJIT();
 LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
```